# Getting MAC ID in Qt

Tags: qt, qtnetwork

I am using the following code to get the MAC ID in Qt.

main.cpp

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include "QtNetwork/QNetworkInterface"
#include "QString"

QString getMacAddress()
{
    foreach(QNetworkInterface interface, QNetworkInterface::allInterfaces())
    {
        // Return only the first non-loopback MAC Address
        if (!(interface.flags() & QNetworkInterface::IsLoopBack))
            return interface.hardwareAddress();
        QString text = interface.hardwareAddress();
        qDebug() << text;
    }
    return QString();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    getMacAddress();
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    return a.exec();
}
```

I am getting nothing in Console? Guide me thanks...

Comment: did you include `CONFIG += console` in your .pro?

Comment: @zzk Yeah I did, FYI here's my project source:

`QT       += core
QT       += network
QT       -= gui
TARGET = qmacid
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
` I presume there is some problem in **getMacAddress()** function.

Comment: huh..`return interface.hardwareAddress();` so perhaps it returns there without printing anything.

Comment: Right, how can I save it to QString? OR do I need to convert it or something?

Comment: Look at interface.allAddresses() instead of just the hardwareAddress.

Comment: @Sosukodo thanks for it, right, how I got to show it on my Console window?? kindly help

Comment: Remove your conditional that checks for IsLoopBack.

Comment: The hardwareAddress is obviously empty for the interface that's passing your conditional so you should look at all interfaces with your own eyes to see what data *is* available.

Comment: @Sosukodo Yeah I did, but it displays nothing in the COnsole

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Obtaining MAC address on windows in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609953/obtaining-mac-address-on-windows-in-qt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code so show the hardware addresses of each interface:

```
QString getMacAddress()
{
    QString text;
    foreach(QNetworkInterface interface, QNetworkInterface::allInterfaces())
    {
        text += "Interface:"+interface.hardwareAddress()+"\n";
    }
    return text;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    printf( "%s\n", getMacAddress().toAscii().constData() );
    exit(1);
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: note: to pass QString as `const char *` use `qPrintable(string)`